# How do i set Linkbutton1 to my propertie MyData

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (DropDownListFeeds.SelectedItem.Value == "All")
            {
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

                SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

                query.Lists = "<Lists>" +
                              "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                              "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                              "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagementNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                              "</Lists>";


                query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                                   "<FieldRef Name=\"Date\" Nullable=\"TRUE\"/>";
                query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>";
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

                query.RowLimit = 10;

                DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);



                GridViewNewsFeed.DataSource = dv;
                GridViewNewsFeed.DataBind();



            }
        }

        catch (Exception x)
        {

            Label1.Text = x.Message;
        }

    }
```

Abowe Date and Title i have a Dropdownlist and a Button the code above are for the button.

the code for what happens when i press linkbutton in the first grinview and display it in the other grindview looks like this.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

        query.Lists = "<Lists>" +
                      "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                      "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                      "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagementNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                      "</Lists>";


        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +"<FieldRef Name=\"Authors\" />"+"<FieldRef Name=\"Links\" />"+"<FieldRef Name=\"Contents\" />"+
                           "<FieldRef Name=\"Date\" Nullable=\"TRUE\"/>";
        query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>";
        query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

        query.RowLimit = 10;

        DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);



        GridViewShowMore.DataSource = dv;
        GridViewNewsFeed.DataBind();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a ASP.Net Question more than a Sharepoint one. You dont have to use Connected web parts as that is used for something completely different. (Passing rows of data using a consumber/subcriber type of model).

Anyways, coupld of ways to do this, and the shortest would be:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="text" runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" 
    onclick="LinkButton1_Click" />   

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TypeOfYourOtherWebpart Ctrl = this.Page.FindControl("YourOtherControlID") as TypeOfYourOtherWebpart;
    TypeOfYourOtherWebpart.MyData = "SomeValue";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what are SharePoint built on?Maybe asp??

Comment: and by the way , do i not need any Consumer or Provider , so what should i use? I Dont get it...

Comment: ASP.Net 3.5.  The way i showed above will find the Control on the page (all web parts on the page). I would however suggest that you just use 1 web part. That way you wouldn't have to do a FindControl and could just reference by its name.

Comment: i want only my linkbutton to get and set the property data , i dont get it to work, i have upaded my image in the top

Comment: i want my linkbutton to use property MyData

Comment: for example here `if (ListBox.SelectedItem == null)
            {


                Label1.Text = "Error:You Have Not Selected Anything!";

            }
            else
            {

                
                MyData = ListBox.SelectedItem.Value;` For example here a listbox uses my property Mydata. But now i want a grinview with a linkbutton to use MyData

Comment: Ok. So what I am trying to demonstrate on top is that in Control 2, you can expose a control as public and set its value (such as text). To do this first, you have to get a handle to the control and cast it to its correct type. That is what FindControl as Type does.

Comment: oki i have now only one webpart , with two grindviews when pressing the linkbutton i want to show data in the other grindview, were to start? what should i write in linkbutton to refer

Comment: Ok. So now you are able to refernce the grid views using their IDs. So, where do you want to show MyData? It's just a single string value, so you can't really bind it to a repeater or Grid. You normally bind a Collection to a Gridview. As far as I can tell, you want to pass the value from a dropdown list as a paratmer to your data query? Plaese ellaborate what you want to do with MyData.

Comment: Hi! i dont use Mydata any more because i dont use a connectable anymore. i have now created two grindviews one when i select from dropdownlist it show the title and the title is a linkbutton, now i want to when i press the linkbutton in the first grindview to display more things in the second grinview more things then Title

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7337/discussion-between-morski-martin-and-fox)

Comment: what should i write here, i only displays the newest added right not i want to display the one i click on in grindviews tite. protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            




        }  i want when pressing on linkbutton to display that in detailsview